# How to add $ and decimal to column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Im trying to add decimal and $ to all the rows in a table.  Some of the rows have the $ and . in the correct spot.  I searched on here but did not find a similar question when you have 2 different types of numbers.

The current format is like this:

```
Item 1    $10.00
Item 2    10
Item 3    99.99
Item 4    $120.00
```

I need to have it look like this.

```
Item 1    $10.00
Item 2    $10.00
Item 3    $99.99
Item 4    $120.00
```

Comment: Hi David, welcome to Stack Overflow. Without more context it is not clear what are you trying to do. MySQL does not really output data like you show on your examples. Are you using something else next to it? How are you inserting that data? How are you querying it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not select all the rows that do not start with a `$` and update them, and do the same afterwards with the dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using 2 different columns for currency symbol and the actual value, so that you can make sums and spo on with it easily.

but if you want this.

Use

```
UPDATE table1 SET `value` = CONCAT('$',TRUNCATE(`value`,2)) WHERE `value` NOT LIKE '$%'
```

[TRUNCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) is used to give the numbers 2 digits

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `name` VARCHAR(6),
>   `value` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`name`, `value`)
> VALUES
>   ('Item 1', '$10.00'),
>   ('Item 2', '10'),
>   ('Item 3', '99.99'),
>   ('Item 4', '$120.00');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `value` NOT LIKE '$%'
> ```
>
> ```
> name   | value
> :----- | :----
> Item 2 | 10   
> Item 3 | 99.99
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1 SET `value` = CONCAT('$',TRUNCATE(`value`,2)) WHERE `value` NOT LIKE '$%'
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> name   | value  
> :----- | :------
> Item 1 | $10.00 
> Item 2 | $10.00 
> Item 3 | $99.99 
> Item 4 | $120.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3ca1aa8154b2b32f85a870994a20b770)*

Comment: Thank you sir.  This worked for what I was looking for.  Would it be more advisable to run this within the select statement rather than change the DB?

Comment: It depends, what you are doing with it. You can#t so sum up all pirchase by a customer in a moth. that's why i recommended splitting currency and value. If you want to do it in a query, you have to check it with an IF Clause beforehand, if it has already a currency sign

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Update your_table_name, 
       (SELECT name, CONCAT('$',CAST(REPLACE(value, ',', '.') as DECIMAL(20,2))) as new_value 
        FROM `your_table_name` WHERE INSTR(`value`, '$') = 0) A 
SET your_table_name.value= A.new_value
WHERE your_table_name.name = A.name AND INSTR(your_table_name.`value`, '$') = 0
```